# Xcode cannot find header files when files added in folder reference mode

Tags: objective-c, swift, j2objc

I am trying to add many Objective-C files to my Swift project with folder reference mode that means when I drag and drop my files into project I am selecting "Create Folder Reference".

This is because all of my obj-c files use `#include "/folder/folder/folder/"` for example. These files are generated with [j2objc](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/) project.

Now my problem is when I want to `#import` or `#include` some `.h` of these files in `myproject-Bridging-Header.h` Xcode can't find the header files.
I use `#import "/folder/folder/folder/"` like generated files but no chance.

I add `$(PROJECT_DIR)/` in build settings - search header paths but it does need to write path completely like `$(PROJECT_DIR)/folder/folder/folder/`.
Is there any way to set main folder and Xcode find subfolders ? Or do I need to write every path separately ?

Comment: please, improve your test formatting

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer after many days by myself!

When I drag and drop my files to my project in Xcode in mode "Create Folder Reference", just a reference to the files is added to Xcode and the files were in their folder where in my Mac.

I resolve this problem by add files to project's folder manually and then drag and drop from that location to Xcode. After that, I could access my file by its address in `myproject-Bridging-Header.h` like `#import "/folder/folder/folder/file.h"`

Comment: Yeah, it's an Xcode issue, which custom rules cannot work around.